NTFS permissions on fileshare
I have a fileshare with the following structure:
\server\share\Users\username\folder\subfolder\file.txt
I am trying to deny users to read and list folder contents at level \server\share but I need them to grant write and modify permissions at level \server\share\Users\username
I make use of group permissions to make the first deny and granting permissions "per user" at "username" level.
I verified I cacn write files on my username folder but programs like eclipse are giving me a message like this:
"The configuration area at "\server\share\users\username\eclipse" is not writable. Please choose a writable location using -configuration command line option."
I don't know what denies eclipse to write on this folder.
I saw that eclipse is creating a new folder at configuration area but is not creating the config.ini file. As a user, I can create a file.
